# How to install PECL/XMLRPCi from within Plesk 18.0.49

Tags: php, plesk

Being a newbee with Plesk, I'm trying to install PECL extension XMLRPCi from within Plesk 18.0.49, but I get this error message:

Failed to download pecl/XMLRPCi within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 1.0, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/XMLRPCi-1.0" to install
install failed

How can I resolve this? How can I change the channel?

Comment: It's probably best if you ask this over on Plesk's [forum](https://talk.plesk.com/), since most users here are more familiar with cPanel.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that!